# Save and Update Yii FW

Tags: php, yii

I'm having little less experience with Yii. Can anyone please help me with following?

In **Yii Framework** how exactly we can *save and update* Many to Many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the following topic.

You may use behavior solution or just take pieces of code for building your own logic.

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6905-please-test-my-ar-enhancement-automatically-sync-many-many-table-when-calling-save/page__view__findpost__p__36659